# How to prevent a regex to match an empty path?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to define two different locations. 
The first one (A) serves files from an alias. The second one (B) from a proxy_pass.

(B) uses a regular expression to match a path.

They both work separately.

```
# configuration (A)
location /some-path {
  alias /dev/folder/dist;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

# configuration (B) 
location ~ ^/some-path/([\w\-]+-[\w$]+)/(\w+) {
  proxy_pass http://web-app/some-path/$1/$2;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

I'd like the locations to respond to these URLs :

- http://domain.local/some-path/example-000 (A)
- http://domain.local/some-path/example-000/something (B)

Unfortunately http://domain.local/some-path/example-000 returns a 404 from the application behind the (B).

The app returns this weird message `404 "/some-path/example-000/index"`

What kind of change can I do to make it work?

Comment: What is `/some-path/example-000` supposed to return. It looks like it morphs into `/some-path/example-000/index.html` in block (A), which is then processed by block (B).

Comment: It's exactly what's happening. `/some-path/example-000` serves `/dev/folder/dist/example-000/index.html`. If it's the normal behavior, what can I do to keep both URLs accessible?